# Segfault on TTF_Quit call when app built with cabal

Tags: haskell, segmentation-fault, sdl, cabal

I have a strange issue. I created a simple app in haskell with sdl, and when it's built with ghc there no problems, but when it's built with cabal I have a segfault after closing my app. I'm noticed that when Graphics.UI.SDL.TTF.General.quit call is commented there are no problems too.

I'm trying to do the thing on Ubuntu 12.04 with ghc 7.4.1. Here is my cabal file:

```
Name:           simple app
Version:        0.0.0.1
Build-Type:     Simple
Cabal-Version:  >= 1.8
Executable invaders
  Main-is:         App.hs
  Build-Depends:   base > 3 && < 5,
                   mtl,
                   SDL,
                   SDL-image,
                   SDL-ttf
```

And here is my app(it's at most a code from lesson08 of [LasyFooHaskell](https://github.com/snkkid/LazyFooHaskell))

```
module App where

import Data.Word

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader

import Graphics.UI.SDL
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Image

import Graphics.UI.SDL.TTF
import qualified Graphics.UI.SDL.TTF.General as TTFG

screenWidth = 640
screenHeight = 480
screenBpp = 32

data MessageDir = MessageDir {
     upMessage    :: Surface,
     downMessage  :: Surface,
     leftMessage  :: Surface,
     rightMessage :: Surface
}

data AppConfig = AppConfig {
     screen       :: Surface,
     background   :: Surface,
     messageDir   :: MessageDir
}

type AppState = StateT (Maybe Surface) IO
type AppEnv = ReaderT AppConfig AppState

runLoop :: AppConfig -> IO()
runLoop config = (evalStateT . runReaderT loop) config Nothing

loadImage :: String -> Maybe (Word8, Word8, Word8) -> IO Surface
loadImage filename colorKey = load filename >>= displayFormat >>= setColorKey' colorKey

setColorKey' Nothing s = return s
setColorKey' (Just (r, g, b)) surface = (mapRGB . surfaceGetPixelFormat) surface r g b >>= setColorKey surface [SrcColorKey] >> return surface

applySurface :: Int -> Int -> Surface -> Surface -> Maybe Rect -> IO Bool
applySurface x y src dst clip = blitSurface src clip dst offset
             where offset = Just Rect { rectX = x, rectY = y, rectW = 0, rectH = 0 }

initEnv :: IO AppConfig
initEnv = do
        screen <- setVideoMode screenWidth screenHeight screenBpp [SWSurface]
        setCaption "Press an Arrow Key" []

        background      <- loadImage "res/img/background.png" $ Just (0x00, 0xff, 0xff)
        font            <- openFont "res/lazy.ttf" 72

        upMessage       <- renderTextSolid font "Up was pressed" textColor
        downMessage     <- renderTextSolid font "Down was pressed" textColor
        leftMessage     <- renderTextSolid font "Left was pressed" textColor
        rightMessage    <- renderTextSolid font "Right was pressed" textColor

        applySurface 0 0 background screen Nothing

        let msgDir = MessageDir upMessage downMessage leftMessage rightMessage
        return $ AppConfig screen background msgDir
      where textColor = Color 0 0 0

loop :: AppEnv ()
loop = do

     quit <- whileEvents $ \event -> do
       case event of 
         (KeyDown (Keysym key _ _)) -> do
           mdir <- messageDir `liftM` ask
           case key of
             SDLK_UP    -> put $ Just $ upMessage mdir
             SDLK_DOWN  -> put $ Just $ downMessage mdir
             SDLK_LEFT  -> put $ Just $ leftMessage mdir
             SDLK_RIGHT -> put $ Just $ rightMessage mdir
             _          -> put Nothing
         _ -> return ()

     screen     <- screen `liftM` ask
     background <- background `liftM` ask
     msg        <- get

     case msg of
          Nothing       -> return ()
          Just message  -> do
               applySurface' 0 0 background screen Nothing
               applySurface' ((screenWidth - surfaceGetWidth message) `div` 2) ((screenHeight - surfaceGetHeight message) `div` 2) message screen Nothing
               put Nothing

     liftIO $ Graphics.UI.SDL.flip screen

     unless quit loop

  where applySurface' x y src dst clip = liftIO (applySurface x y src dst clip)

whileEvents :: MonadIO m => (Event -> m()) -> m Bool
whileEvents act = do
            event <- liftIO pollEvent
            case event of
                 Quit -> return True
                 NoEvent -> return False
                 _ -> do
                   act event
                   whileEvents act

main = withInit [InitEverything] $ do
     result <- TTFG.init
     if not result
        then putStr "Failed to init ttf\n"
        else do
             env <- initEnv
             runLoop env
             ttfWasInit <- TTFG.wasInit
             case ttfWasInit of
               True -> TTFG.quit
               False -> return ()
```

What's I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this shows segfault when compiled with optimizations. 
I tried it with `-O0` and got no segfault whereas `-O2` gives the segfault.

The cabal build version gives segfault by default. This is probably because cabal enables optimizations by default.

Try building by

```
cabal configure --disable-optimization
cabal build
```

Comment: Yes, it's the solution. Thank you. However, I got segfault after

"cabal configure --disable-optimization"

and get no one after I set "ghc-options: -O0" in the .cabal file